# Creating new column by combining existing columns conditionally in R

Tags: r

Dear members please help me get to the solution to below issue.

df.data

```
 Team_1     Team_2       Cond           
  RKS         MGR          1           
  MGR         RKS          2           
  VSK         LSR          1           
  LSR     VSK          2
```

Want to create new dataframe that if Cond = 1 New_Column = Team_1 Vs Team_2 else Team_2 Vs Team_1

Expected Result

df.Newdata

```
 Team_1     Team_2       Cond       New_Column    
  RKS         MGR          1           RKS Vs MGR
  MGR         RKS          2           RKS Vs MGR
  VSK         LSR          1           VSK Vs LSR
  LSR         VSK          2           VSK Vs LSR
```

Comment: It's helpful if you show what you've tried so far and what hasn't worked. There are a lot of similar questions already on SO, but more specifics would help with knowing how this is different from other questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ifelse` here, with the `Cond` column determining which team comes first in the comparison.

```
df$New_Column <- ifelse(df$Cond == 1,
                        paste0(df$Team_1, " Vs ", df$Team_2),
                        paste0(df$Team_2, " Vs ", df$Team_1))
df

  Team_1 Team_2 Cond New_Column
1    RKS    MGR    1 RKS Vs MGR
2    MGR    RKS    2 RKS Vs MGR
3    VSK    LSR    1 VSK Vs LSR
4    LSR    VSK    2 VSK Vs LSR
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `sqldf` for the data frame `df`:

```
df <- sqldf("SELECT Team_1, Team_2, Cond, CASE 
                                              WHEN  Cond = 1 THEN Team_1 || ' Vs ' || Team_2
                                              WHEN  Cond = 2 THEN Team_2 || ' Vs ' || Team_1 
                                              END New_Column
             FROM df ")
```

Answer (score 0):

As the 'Cond' column is column index, it can also be utilized in an different way to extract the element value with `row/column` indexing

```
# matrix of row/column index
m1 <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$Cond)
# change the column index to get the value in alternate column
m2 <- cbind(m1[,1], 3 - m1[,2])
# paste the extracted values to create new column
df1$New_Column <- paste(df1[m1], "Vs", df1[m2])
```

#### Benchmarks

Slight change in elapsed time on a 1e7 dataset

```
df2 <- df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 1e7), ]

system.time({
    m1 <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df2)), df2$Cond)
    m2 <- cbind(m1[,1], 3 - m1[,2])
    paste(df2[m1], "Vs", df2[m2])

})
#user  system elapsed 
# 25.926   2.548  28.983 

system.time({
 ifelse(df2$Cond == 1,
                        paste0(df2$Team_1, " Vs ", df2$Team_2),
                        paste0(df2$Team_2, " Vs ", df2$Team_1))

})
# user  system elapsed 
# 28.446   1.934  30.542
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Team_1 = c("RKS", "MGR", "VSK", "LSR"), Team_2 = c("MGR", 
  "RKS", "LSR", "VSK"), Cond = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```